# Remove new Firefox autofill color

Tags: css, firefox, input, autofill, yellow

A few days ago my Firefox Developer Edition updated to version 67.0b2 (64 bit). Since then all autofilled input fields have a yellow background, on literally every website.

How can I get rid of the yellow autofill color?

Changing inset box-shadow color doesn't seem to work like it does in Chrome.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

### Firefox 94 and newer

Just change the input's background color in your css:

```
input:autofill {
  background: #fff; /* or any other */
}
```

If you wish to remove the autofill background only in your Firefox browser, set `layout.css.autofill.background` to `false` in `about:config`.

### Firefox 67 (2019-05-21) - 94 (2021-11-02; excluding)

Add this to your css:

```
input {
  filter: none;
}
```

Why? At the bottom of `view-source:resource://gre-resources/forms.css` we can see this:

```
:-moz-autofill, :-moz-autofill-preview {
  filter: grayscale(21%) brightness(88%) contrast(161%) invert(10%) sepia(40%) saturate(206%);
}
```

And that is the cause of the yellow autofill background color.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me using Firefox 99.

```css
box-shadow: 0 0 0 40px {COLOR} inset !important;
```

unfortunately you can't change the color to transparent, it'll still be yellow.

Answer (score 0):

#### For firefox 94.0+

To make it work, additionally, I had to change this option to `false` in `about:config`:

```
layout.css.autofill.background = false
```

Comment: Any way to make it work without asking users to change their browser's settings?

Comment: I don't know, I would ask firefox team about that, or rise a bug report in their bugzilla site.