# Any way to remove Firefox textbox style when filling with saved login?

Tags: css, firefox

It looks like one of the latest updates to firefox now style text inputs when using a password saved in the browser. I really hate how this yellow looks. Is it possible to remove this styling?

I thought it would just be a matter of adding something like:

```
-webkit-appearance: none;
-moz-appearance: none;
appearance: none;
```

That didn't seem to do anything. Is there anything that can be done about this?

This is what it looks like, I just don't want this yellow.

[image: Here's an example]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove new Firefox autofill color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55228377/remove-new-firefox-autofill-color)

Answer (score 1):

Try this and see if it makes a difference.

```
input:-webkit-autofill 
{
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 0px 9999px white;
}
```

Source: https://techstacker.com/posts/np6yd7A5FzLtpuwku/css-how-to-remove-the-yellow-background-color-on-input

Comment: Firefox isn't a Webkit browser, so it doesn't support that. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:-webkit-autofill  There has been discussion about adding :-moz-autofill to Firefox, but that hasn't happened yet: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=740979

Answer (score 0):

```
input {
  filter: none;
}
```

Hope this will help you.